# sed replace brackets with underscore

Tags: replace, sed

I am a sed beginner and trying to do a replace on the following string:

`a_b0_24[0][1]` should be changed to     `a_b0_24_0__1_`

There are only numbers within brackets. The text before brackets are only numbers, alphabets or underscore.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

check this out:

```
kent$  echo 'a_b0_24[0][1]'|sed 's/[][]/_/g'
a_b0_24_0__1_
```

Comment: There could be any number of open and close brackets!

Comment: so what？ did u try my cmd?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'y/[]/__/' file
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is I don't want to change all the [] and just some of them which starts with a backslash. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have some text in a bash variable called `TEXT`:

```
$ echo $TEXT | sed -e 's/\[\|\]/_/g'
```

To break that down:

- The regex to match brackets should look something like "[|]". The brackets are literals, and the pipe in the middle means "or". However, since brackets have a meta-meaning in the regex language, you need to escape them so that they're interpreted as literals (thus the backslashes). As for escaping the pipe, I'm not entirely sure why it's necessary tbh, but it wouldn't work without it.
- The "g" simply means "do this for all matches, not just the first one" (it stands for "global").

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think my question was not well written.
Suppose we have two cases:

One with a backslash in the file (this needs to be changed)
\a_b0_24[0][1] should be a_b0_24_0__1_

One without a backslash in the file
C_D1_24[0][1] should remain the same C_D1_24[0][1]

Thanks

Comment: Thanks man. you are life saver. I am also trying to work on that. BTW, There could be one to many number of brackets! I appreciate that.

Comment: @AmirYazdanbakhsh In the OP you said that your two constraints were that the preceding text could only be numbers, alphabetic characers, or underscores. Here, however, you say something about needing a backslash? Could you elaborate?

Comment: My bad. As I mentioned there could be two cases in the file. Those which needs to be changed and those which don't. If there is a backslash it means we need to replace brackets with underscore, otherwise we should leave them unchanged.

Comment: @joshfl13 I got something for one bracket. echo \\_azfa4[3] | sed -n 's/\\\([^\[]*\)\[\([0-9]*\)\]/\1_\2_/p'

Comment: Huh, I'd think that'd work for multiple sets because of the * after [0-9].

Comment: No. It means it could have many digits within the bracket. What I want is it could have many number of brackets. My code doesn't capture this case \_azfa4[3][4].

Comment: I think it can not be done in one run. If I use what you have said, then how can I grab the digits within brackets?

Comment: @AmirYazdanbakhsh, you need to update your question with all these additional requirements.